# Core Text ( swift ) : set frame for every letter

Tags: ios, swift, core-text

When archiving the effect below:

[image: 888]

- convert every Chinese letter to a `NSAttributedString`
- convert every `NSAttributedString`  to a `CTLine`

So every Chinese letter is a `CTLine`

Then the key math problem is to calculate the origin of background image / letter

```
     let bgGrip = UIImage(named: "x")
    
    
     func drawGrips(m info: TxtRenderInfo, lnH lnHeight: CGFloat, index i: Int, dB beginIdx: Int, lineOrigin lnOrigin: CGPoint, context ctx: CGContext, lnAscent lineAscent: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
            let content = info.strArr[i - beginIdx]
            let glyphCount = content.count
            var frameImg = TextContentConst.bgImgFrame
            let lnOffsset = (TextContentConst.padding - lnHeight) * 0.5
            var lineOrigin = lnOrigin
            lineOrigin.y -= lnOffsset
            var textP = lineOrigin
            for idx in 0..<glyphCount{
                  let pieX = String(content[idx])
                  let ln = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(pieX.word)
                  let lnSize = ln.lnSize
                  let typeOriginX = TextContentConst.padding * CGFloat(idx + 1)
                  textP.x = typeOriginX + (TextContentConst.padding - lnSize.width) * 0.5
                  ctx.textPosition = textP
                  frameImg.origin.x = typeOriginX
                  frameImg.origin.y = lineOrigin.y + lineAscent - TextContentConst.bgImgFrame.size.height + TextContentConst.offsetP.y
                  // draw image
                  bgGrip?.draw(in: frameImg)
                  // draw text
                  CTLineDraw(ln, ctx)
            }
            return lnOffsset
        }
    
    extension CTLine{
        var lnSize: CGSize{
            var lnAscent:CGFloat      = 0
            var lnDescent:CGFloat     = 0
            var lnLeading:CGFloat     = 0
            let glyphW = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(self , &lnAscent, &lnDescent, &lnLeading)
            let lnHeight = lnAscent + lnDescent + lnLeading
            return CGSize(width: CGFloat(glyphW), height: lnHeight)
        }
    }
```

`CTLine` -> `CTRun` -> `CGGlyph`

a Chinese letter is a `CTLine`,  **not very nice**.

So how to improve the code?

[github repo](https://github.com/coyingcat/TxtReader/tree/master/feature/five)

Comment: Hi. A few days ago faced with similar problem. Have you find a solution?

Comment: The solution is to use CTLine , a letter is a CTLine. I have tried `CTRun draw range`. Not well @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66719719/core-text-set-frame-for-every-letter-with-ctrundraw